# how to properly define functions with templates

Tags: c++, c, templates, cuda

I am having trouble to understand why I get unresolved external symbol when I am trying to build a program. I have 3 files. Lets say

```
main.cpp
file.cu
headerfile.h
```

I have these 2 const variables defined in my main function in the `main.cpp` file:

```
const uint             N = 1048576;
const uint          base = 1024;
```

I have also defined the functions needed in a `headerfile.h`:

```
template <const uint N, const uint base>
void F1(
    float2 *d_S_x,
    float2 *d_S_y,
    bool *S_yy,
    CCP *dev_CP,
    uint batchSize,
    uint batchLength
);
```

along with others like:

```
...
extern "C" uint bitonicSort(
    float2 *d_P_out,
    float2 *d_P_in,
    uint batchSize,
    uint arrayLength,
    uint dir,
    uint xy
);
...
```

I have to use templates cause the variables `N` and `base` will be used in allocating shared memory on the device so i need to have const variables. The `F1` function is like an interface function in a `file.cu` from where I will launch my kernels.
Now from the `main.cpp` I call the F1 normally with

`F1 <N,base> ( d_S_x, d_S_y, d_S_yy, dev_CP, batchsize, batchLength);`

and I launch some kernels from within  the `F1` (or the other function shown in error the `BF`) like:

```
MinReduction <N, base> <<< 1, base >>>(dev_CP);
```

Is there something wrong with the definitions of the functions in .h file? I think I am missing something with the use of extern along with template right?
The errors are:

```
Error 4 error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals E:\D....exe
Error 3 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl BF<1048576,1024>(struct float2 *,struct CCP *)" (??$BruteForce@$0BAAAAA@$0EAA@@@YAXPAUfloat2@@PAUCCP@@@Z) E:\...main.obj
Error 2 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl F1<1048576,1024>(struct float2 *,struct float2 *,bool *,struct CCP *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (??$closest_pair@$0BAAAAA@$0EAA@@@YAXPAUfloat2@@0PA_NPAUCCP@@II@Z) E:\..main.obj
```

Where should I define the functions if not in the `headerfile.h`? I understand that  Extern tells the compiler that you are not declaring a new variable, but instead referring to a variable declared elsewhere. But defining extern along with template doesnt work right?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any explicit specialization declarations must be visible at the time of the template instantiation. I suspect that your explicit/implicit specializations of the template functions are either visible only in the `file.cu` translation unit and not in the main file or they miss the template declaration where performed.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal compilable example, e.g.: without your extern functions, just the template stuff. Also note that you can use shared memory dynamically.

Comment: @bamboon The code with the extern is working fine, I have tested it before I add the new functions that I need with templates etc. I am aware of dynamic allocation but I need to compile it with static allocation of shared memory since there is no need. After all throughout the program the shared memory usage is the same but it depends on the initial values of N and base.

Comment: @JackOLantern I have included the header in the main function. What else should I try?

Comment: What is shown here is a declaration, not a definition, which is the part which provides the function body. Please mention where all the declarations and definitions went, for one misbehaving function.

Answer (score 3):

All explicit specialization declarations must be visible at the time of the template instantiation.

From your (incomplete) post, it seems that you have the following (simplified) scenario:

`main.cu file`

```
const int             N = 1048576;
const int          base = 1024;

#include "test.cuh"

int main() {

    F1<N,base>();

    return 0;
}
```

`test.cuh file`

```
template<const int N, const int base> void F1();
```

`test.cu file`

```
template<int N, int base> void F1() { }
```

This structure will give the following error message

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl F1<1048576,1024>(void)" (??$F1@$0BAAAAA@$0EAA@@@YAXXZ)
```

The reason is that the implicit specialization occurring in the `F1<N,base>` call of in the `main.cu` file is not visible in the translational unit where `F1` is defined (the `test.cu` file).

You should use something like

```
const int             N = 1048576;
const int          base = 1024;

template<int N, int base> void F1() { };

int main() {

    F1<N,base>();

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, the implicit specialization `F1<N,base>();` occurring in the `main.cu` file occurs in the same translational unit where `F1` is defined.

Your question is not related to CUDA and is a problem of using templates in C++. You may wish to take a look at this [guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-1) for more immediate information.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but what I am trying to do is to use definitions in the `headerfile.h` and not redefining or declaring it inside the main.cpp file. I am reading the guide you mentioned as well. :)

Answer (score -1):

While [JackOLantern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20221944/1593077) is quite relevant, let's be a bit more CUDA-specific: I wonder if you really need these two template variables.

- You're passing 'base' as the block size, meaning you already have some behavior which does not assume its value. So, is it so important to 'know' it in advance for some part of the code?
- As for N, I don't know what you use it for, but 1,048,576 = 2^20 is a bit too perfect a number. I wonder - can't you make it a constant? Or pass it to the kernel as an enum value?

So, you might be creating the problem for yourself... (or you might not, but others in your situation may well be doing so).

Comment: Hello. What I am trying to do is place the definition of the 2 interface functions in the `headerfile.h`. Dont bother about the values of N and base. They dont change throughout the program. I ve already defined them as constant.